# Удалить строку из базы данных, если уже прошли сутки, с момента записи даты (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Всем привет.

Есть такой формат даты: 2013-10-26 14:25:02. Необходимо удалить строки, где, допустим, дата = 2013-10-25 14:25:02 или более ранняя, как это сделать?

Пробовал так:

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `date` > (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Поменяйте знак > на <

NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY - это что, завтрашний день проверяется, что ли?

Comment: @Deus, пробовал, удаляет 2013-10-26 14:25:02 (сегодняшнюю)

Comment: @Deus, благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

WHERE date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)